# BOOL changes from YES to NO between ViewControllers by itself?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4

I just dont get it.. this happens here and there but I cant find a ryme or reason. 
Ive searched SO for awhile with no luck.. maybe you guys can tell me what Im doing wrong?

I am setting a BOOL in ViewController_A from ViewController_B. 
Stepping through the code I see the BOOL change to YES, but when I am sent back to VC_A it is back to NO

Update: this is all on the Main Thread.

Here is my code.

ViewController_A.h

```
BOOL shouldLogin;

@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL shouldLogin;
```

ViewController_A.m

```
@synthesize shouldLogin;


//in viewWillAppear of ViewController_A
if (shouldLogin == YES) {
//do something - im trying to get in here but I cant because the BOOL is NO when I come back to this view

}
```

Here is how I set the BOOL in ViewController_B

```
    ViewController_A * vc = [[ViewController_A alloc]init];
    vc.shouldLogin = YES; 
   //stepping through the code and looking at the value, shouldLogin shows YES 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // this drops down VC_B which will show VC_A

//now VC_A just came into view and the BOOL is now NO which makes the compiler skip over my IF statement
```

**UPDATED: removed the release call that I had, but still same issue.**

Comment: Um..what?  Am I missing something?  You alloc `vc`, then set shouldLogin to YES, then immediately deallocate it by sending a `release` message...

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I tried both with that release and without. I left it in there while posting this Question, but it doesnt make a difference.. it still wont work.

Comment: It wont work with or without the `release` because the `ViewController_A` that you creating in `ViewController_B` is not the same `ViewController_A` that is already instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code in `ViewController_B` is creating a completely new `ViewController_A`, setting the `shouldLogin` flag and then immediately destroying that instantiation of `ViewController_A`.  I doubt this is what you intend to do.

I assume you want to set the `shouldLogin` flag on a previously instantiated `ViewController_A`.  You will need to pass a pointer to `ViewController_A` to your `ViewController_B` and then use this pointer to set the flag in `ViewController_B`.  You could do this with a custom `init` method on `ViewController_B` that takes a pointer to `ViewController_A` and stores it for use by `ViewController_B`.

Alternatively, you could just create a property on `ViewController_B` that can store a pointer to `ViewController_A` and get `ViewController_A` to set this property after the `ViewController_B` has been created.  Something like:

```
@interface ViewController_B : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,retain) ViewController_A *originalViewController;

@end

@implementation ViewController_B

@synthesize originalViewController;

- (void)someMethod {
    originalViewController.shouldLogin = YES; 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end

@implementation ViewController_A 

-(void)someOtherMethod {
     ViewController_B *vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
     vcB.originalViewController = self;

     // do something with vcB
}

@end
```

Forgive any typos/errors, I haven't actually tried to run this.

Comment: thank you all for helping me understand this - Ive ran into it here and there and just end up adding BOOLs to the AppDelegate. Glad I took the time to understand whats happening there. Thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 1):

I assume your view controller A existed before you pushed view controller B.  In that case you need to reference back to the original view controller, not just create a new one.  You are not touching the original view controller anywhere in this code so it makes perfect sense that it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

ViewController_A is a class, not an object.  shouldLogin can only be accessed by an object of class ViewController_A.

The object (or instance) of ViewController_A that you had shown previously is NOT the same as the instance in your ViewController_B code.  The code that you display creates a brand new ViewController_A object, sets the boolean to YES on that object, and then immediately destroys that object.  It never changed anything inside the ViewController_A instance you had before you presented your ViewController_B instance, so when you return to display the original ViewController_A, it's exactly as it was--complete with shouldLogin set to NO.

Since shouldLogin seems like a variable multiple view controllers will need access to, I would set it up in another class entirely (that both view controllers can access).  For variables such as these, I tend to make a Singleton class and share access to that object around the areas it's needed.  There are other ways to do this, of course, but I find that the simplest.